# ValueError: shapes (13,13) and (1,1) not aligned: 13 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0) - Multi Layer Perceptron

Tags: python, mlp

I have a code of a MultiLayer Perceptron with 2 epocs and eta = 0.01 but I keep getting this error.

```
ValueError: shapes (13,13) and (1,1) not aligned: 13 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? What can I do or verify in my code in order to solve this?

Comment: Could you provide a bit of code ?
Also, supposing you use tensorflow: `input_shape = model.layers[0].input_shape`
and maybe `weight_shapes = [layer.get_weights()[0].shape for layer in model.layers if hasattr(layer, 'get_weights')]` (i'm not too sure of the syntax)

Comment: for _ in range(epochs):
    # Feedforward
    hidden_layer = sigmoid(np.dot(X, wHidden))
    output = sigmoid(np.dot(hidden_layer, wOutput))
    
    # Error calculation
    error = Y - output
    errors.append(np.mean(np.abs(error)))
    
    # Backpropagation
    delta_output = error * sigmoid_derivative(output)
    delta_hidden = delta_output.dot(wOutput.T) * sigmoid_derivative(hidden_layer) #it says the error is in this line:

     # Weight Update
    wOutput += hidden_layer.T.dot(delta_output) * eta
    wHidden += X.T.dot(delta_hidden) * eta

Comment: Also I didn't use tensorflow. Only numpy and matplotlib.pyplot as libraries.

Comment: Please edit the post with the code in back quotes :)